# Adding 2 decimal number gives wrong result in Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a problem with the following statement

trace(10.12+13.75)
//output 23.869999999999997

Can anybody explain me why is this so and how to get exact 23.87 out of this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214003/is-there-a-fixed-point-library-for-actionscript-3

Comment: Thank You!, I was doing similar one from Allan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of the precision of IEEE format.

Simplest would be to use toFixed.

```
var num:Number = 10.12+13.75;
var numStr:String = num.toFixed(2);
var num2:Number = new Number(numStr);
```

Comment: Pranav, num2 should be of type Number.

Comment: num = Math.round(num*100)/100; will this be OK?

Comment: @sameerjain, sure. It, however, being a numeric operation, adds the same inconsistencies you encountered in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Computer floating point numbers are not perfectly accurate. JavaScript (and I assume ActionScript, as it's a variant) uses [64-bit IEEE 754 values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) ([ECMAScript spec ref](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5)). The best example of this imprecision is probably `0.1 + 0.2`, which comes out to `0.30000000000000004`. To get `23.87`, you'll have to round.

If you're doing financial math, you may (or may not) be better off using a library that does *decimal* math rather than IEEE floating point (something akin to Java's `BigDecimal` class or C#'s `decimal` type). But note that decimal types have their own limitations, such as not being able to represent `1 / 3` accurately.