# Simple Flash AS3 counter adding unnecessary decimals

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a simple counter application for Flash (AS3) and have stripped it back to the bare minimum as I am encountering a very simple but core problem.

There are two buttons on the stage, one that adds 1.9 to a variable when pressed and one that subtracts 1.9 to the variable when pressed. There is then a dynamic text box that displays the value of the variable as a string.

The problem I am having is that once the counter gets to what shout be 5.7, it displays "5.69999999999" and this continues from then on from then with the occasional number being wrong. i.e. "15.200000000001" etc.

My code is below, I would appreciate if anyone can shed any light on what is going wrong.

```
var count:Number= 0;
counter.text = '0';

myBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick1);
myBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick2);

function btnClick1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    addCount();
}

function btnClick2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    takeCount();
}

function addCount():void
{
    count += 1.9;
    counter.text = count.toString();
}

function takeCount():void
{
    count -=1.9;
    counter.text = count.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your problem and cannot find the source of it. However you could use a simple rounding sytem to fix it such as

```
var count:Number= 0;
counter.text = "0";

myBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick1);
myBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick2);

function btnClick1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
addCount();
}

function btnClick2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

takeCount();
}

function addCount():void
{
count += 1.9;
count=roundDecimal(count, 1)
counter.text = count.toString();
}

function takeCount():void
{
count -=1.9;
count=roundDecimal(count, 1)
counter.text = count.toString();
}

function roundDecimal(num:Number, precision:int):Number{

var decimal:Number = Math.pow(10, precision);

return Math.round(decimal* num) / decimal;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has remedied the problem albeit an unnecessary workaround for a simple problem. Still doesn't make any sense to me but it is now functioning.

Comment: It does seem like a bug on flash's side, but I'm happy I helped.

Comment: While doing something else I found this, it is a flash problem       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015755/adding-2-decimal-number-gives-wrong-result-in-action-script

Comment: That's the main problem:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: BTW, the actual problem arises from Flash player using `double` type for all of the floating-point `Number`s under the hood, while the math coprocessor registers are 10 bytes long, which equals to `extended` type of Pascal (Turbo Pascal 6.0), so that each time Flash tries to invoke coprocessor functions at assembly levels, the 8-byte to 10-byte float typecast is performed, and then backwards. This "bug" might eventually go away if all the computations will be performed in 8-byte floats, or probably 16-byte floats as modern 64-bit processors will progress.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the text to `count.toString()` you can use `toFixed()` function, that will return a fixed-decimal precision text. Give it a parameter of required decimal digits to output, and you're set, without any `Math.pow()` tricks.

```
counter.text=count.toFixed(1);
```

[The `Number.toFixed()` manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29)